# Error in converting HTML with images to PDF using itextsharp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, itext

In my application first am allowing the user to create html document using CKEDITOR where user can can create html document and can insert image, form fields etc. the generated HTML document is than converted into PDF.
If HTML document contains plain text than PDF file gets created successfully but if user inserts image in it than gives error.
code for creating PDF document.

```
public ActionResult CreateFile(FormCollection data)
    {
        var filename = data["filename"];
        var htmlContent = data["content"];
        string sFilePath = Server.MapPath(_createdPDF + filename + ".html");
        htmlContent = htmlContent.Trim();
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(sFilePath))
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sFilePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    w.Write(htmlContent);
                }
            }
            createPDF(sFilePath);
        }

        return View();
    }

    private MemoryStream createPDF(string sFilePath)
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sFilePath);
        string name = Server.MapPath(_createdPDF + filename + ".pdf");
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        TextReader tr = new StringReader(sFilePath);
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);
        string urldir = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
        urldir = urldir.Substring(0, urldir.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        Response.Write(urldir);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
        string htmlText = "";
        StreamReader sr;
        sr = System.IO.File.OpenText(sFilePath);
        htmlText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        Response.Write(htmlText);
        var props = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
        props["img_baseurl"] = @"C:\Documents and Settings\shubham\My Documents\visdatemplatemanger\visdatemplatemanger\";
        List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(htmlText), null,props);
        for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
        {
            document.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
        }
        document.Close();
        System.IO.File.Delete(sFilePath);
        UploadURL(name);
        return ms;
    }
```

The error that i get if image is included in HTML document is:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\PDFimages\rectangle-shape.png'.
```

Answer (score 0):

iTextSharp will try to resolve relative images for HTTP-based documents but ones served from the filesystem you need to either provide absolute paths or provide a base for it to search from.

```
//Image search base, path will be concatenated directly so make sure it contains a trailing slash
var props = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
props["img_baseurl"] = @"c:\images\";

//Include the props from above
htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, null, props);
```

Comment: In this application am allowing the user to upload image. the path can be anything. 
What i want is to convert HTML file (can contain image, table, form fields etc..) into PDF document.
Above code works fine if user creates a file that contains only text and not any images . Please provide solution for this

Comment: If the user can upload an image then you just need to store the image in a folder on the server and point the above code to that folder.

Comment: I did as you said but still am getting the error as "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\shubham\My Documents\visdatemplatemanger\PDFimages\rectangle-shape.png'." All the images that i allow the user to include in PDF are stored in C:\Documents and Settings\shubham\My Documents\visdatemplatemanger\PDFimages\

Comment: So does your HTML point to `/PDFimages/rectangle-shape.png`? If so, you need to point the `img_baseurl` up one folder.

Comment: Hi Chris,when i do           props["img_baseurl"] = "C:\Source\NinjaWeb\Development\Source.Reporting\Ninja.Web\Content\Images"; the program takes the path as C:\Source\NinjaWeb\Development\Source.Reporting\Ninja.Web\Content\Images\Content\Images

If i do just "C:\Source\NinjaWeb\Development\Source.Reporting\Ninja.Web" it gives NullRef.Exception. 

What is the solution?

Comment: @nsarchar, please post your comment as a question. Also, please remember that `HTMLWorker` has been deprecated for a very long time and this answer does not directly apply to the more current and supported XMLWorker.