# Generate PDF from a HTML page with images using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I used iTextSharp.dll to create pdf. But that works only for text HTML content. If I use images on my page it throws an exception that images are not found.

my Design file

```
<asp:Panel ID="pdfPannel" runat="server">
 
      Sample Text
<img src="../Images/image1.png"/>


</asp:Panel>

<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save As PDF" onclick="btnSave_Click" />
```

my method:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=print.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
pdfPannel.RenderControl(hw);
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();

}
```

when I click that save button I'm getting the following error

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\Common
> Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\Images\image1.png'.

Please tell me is there any alternate solution to create pdf.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16061848/231316

Comment: USe Full Path For your Images then Its working.

Comment: When i give full path also its not Working... It take Image path as http://localhost:58095/testProject/D:/testProject/Images/image1.png and that image not displaying in the page.. and it generates pdf for text contents.

Comment: Do you know how to get this working to actually render the page as a pdf and look the same as it would on the web page itself?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. Problem seems with the image's path. Try setting it to **fully qualified path** to images and it will work for you.

Also if you are manipulating `HTML` from the server side code. Then I'll suggest you to map image paths using `Server.MapPath()`. and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks Mayank..

But when I give server.mapPath() it tooks the image url as  "http://localhost:58095/testProject/D:/testProject/Images/Image1.png" and it is not showing the image..

Comment: Its Not working when I give server.mapPath() it tooks the image url as "http://localhost:58095/testProject/D:/testProject/Images/image1.png; and it is not showing the image.

Comment: Well..Problem is with the path itself...I had the same issue...i just implemented fully qualified path and it just worked for me. Also check it's HTML as well. If HTML would validate..code will parse as well...

Comment: for me its not working.. whatever i gave it throughs exception only...
Can you please Share your code.. or mail me@ p.gopalakrishnan@live.com

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
http://localhost:58095/Images/image1.png
```

to get image path. Hope it will help you. `localhost:58095` is Your local machine address.